# Graceful way to handle nil in strptime in CSV processing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am doing some CSV processing with the following code...

```
CSV.foreach(file.tempfile, :headers => true) do |row|
      students[row["person_id"]]["start_dates"] << Date.strptime(row["start_date"], '%m/%d/%Y')
      students[row["person_id"]]["end_dates"] << Date.strptime(row["end_date"], '%m/%d/%Y')
    end
```

However, some of my the cells are blank in my csv file, and my `Date.strptime` is failing with "can't convert nil into String". What is the best/most graceful way to handle this?

I'm hoping for something succinct like...

```
students[row["person_id"]]["last_attend_dates"] << Date.strptime(row["last_attend_date"], '%m/%d/%Y') || ""
```

...but ruby no likey.

Comment: use https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv it will solve all your problem easily.

Comment: `Date.strptime(row["last_attend_date"], '%m/%d/%Y') || ""` won't work because it's passed the nil to strptime (causing an exception) before you get to the `|| ""`.  The closest, syntactically, would be `(Date.strptime(row["last_attend_date"], '%m/%d/%Y') rescue "")` but using rescue like this is a bit dirty in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Crate a custom converter as below :

```
CSV::Converters[:custom] = lambda do |s| 
    Date.strptime(row["last_attend_date"], '%m/%d/%Y') unless s.nil?
end
```

Then do as below :

```
CSV.foreach(file.tempfile, :headers => true, :converters => [:custom]) do |row| ..
```

See the documentation [`Converters`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#Converters) also.

Comment: Actually just adding an 'unless' to my current code seemed to work OK. See it here http://pastie.org/8843313. Seems simpler to me. Am I opening myself up by doing something like this?

Comment: @Lumbee Why would you handle it outside, rather handle it at the time of CSV parsing. CSV giving you the facility, so use it. :-)